# how to show/hide textarea based on select in jquery?

Tags: jquery, forms, select, hide, show

i have a select field and a textarea one. And i am trying to hide/show the textarea in function of the select type i make:

```
<select id="select" name="management">
    <option value="0" selected="">Select One</option>
    <option value="1">Yes</option>
    <option value="0">No</option>
</select>
<textarea id="textarea" name="searching_gig_des" wrap="VIRTUAL" cols="50" rows="5"></textarea>
​
var textarea = $('textarea');.
var select   = $('#select').val();

textarea.hide();

if (select == '1'){
  textarea.show();
}
if (select == '0'){
  textarea.hide();
}
​
```

or [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/patrioticcow/uhv5R/2/)

any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few syntax errors, plus you're not binding the `change` `event` for the `select`

```
$('#select').change(function(){

        var textarea = $('textarea');
        var select   = $(this).val();

        textarea.hide();

        if (select == '1'){
          textarea.show();
        }
        if (select == '0'){
          textarea.hide();
        }
});​
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uhv5R/9/)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#select').change(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    var textarea = $('textarea');

    if (value == '1'){
        textarea.show();
    }
    if (value == '0'){
        textarea.hide();
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `.` from `var textarea = $('textarea');.` and you are good to go.

Btw, I presume that you are trying to `show/hide` textarea based on the drop down value `onload` of the page.

You need to change handler like below if you want to show/hide textarea based on dropdown selection,

```
var $select = $('#select');

$select.change(function() {
    var select = $(this).val();
    if (select == '1') {
        textarea.show();
    }
    if (select == '0') {
        textarea.hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/uhv5R/5/

Bind the JS to the change event, and you had an extra period in there as well.

Answer (score 1):

You have some errors in your jquery code. Also you need to handle change event for your select. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/uhv5R/6/) is the updated jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/uhv5R/6/

Answer (score 1):

First remove the period (`.`) from after the semi-colon on the first `var` line. Then wrap the `if` into a `change()` event-handler, and make the second `if` an `else if`*:

```
var textarea = $('#textarea');
var select   = $('#select').val();

textarea.hide();

$(select).change(
    function(){
        if (select == 1){
          textarea.show();
        }
        else if (select == 0){
          textarea.hide();
        }
    });
```

[JS Fiddle update](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/uhv5R/10/).

---

- This isn't, strictly, necessary. But it does make more sense to me, since the two conditions are related. On the other hand, it could also be just an `else` (rather than `else if`, since there's only really two options).

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var textarea = $('textarea');
$('#select').change(function() {
    if ($(".yes:selected").val() == 1) {
        textarea.show();
    }
    else {
        textarea.hide();
    }
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uMTmm/1/